# Regarding external display issues - the screen cannot properly scale application proportions, but the terminal window can

Tags: 22.04, display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZw4b.png)

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and have customized my desktop with Tweaks. My laptop has a resolution of 2560x1600, while my external monitor is 1920x1080. The Ubuntu system applications scale properly, but other applications do not. How can I resolve this issue?